# Oracle SQL Apex

Tags: mysql

My sql below won't allow me to create the table for Individul_hire and corporate_hire. Any help?

--commands to Create Tables

```
CREATE TABLE Customer ( 
Customer_ID NUMBER (15) PRIMARY KEY, 
First_name VARCHAR2 (15));

create table Corp_Customer(
Customer_ID NUMBER (15), 
Company_Name    varchar2(20),
Contact_Name VARCHAR2 (20),
    Address_1 VARCHAR2 (20), 
  Address_2 VARCHAR2 (25),
  Postcode VARCHAR2 (15) NOT NULL,
  Town VARCHAR2 (15) NOT NULL,
  TelNo NUMBER (15),
  Email VARCHAR2 (35),
  CONSTRAINT PK_Corp_Customer  PRIMARY KEY (Customer_ID),
constraints fk_Corp_Customer foreign key (Customer_ID) references Customer (Customer_ID));

create table Ind_Customer(
Customer_ID NUMBER (15), 
 First_Name VARCHAR2 (15),
Surname varchar2(15),
    Address_1 VARCHAR2 (20), 
  Address_2 VARCHAR2 (25),
  Postcode VARCHAR2 (15) NOT NULL,
  Town VARCHAR2 (15) NOT NULL,
  TelNo NUMBER (15),
  Email VARCHAR2 (35) UNIQUE,
  Date_Of_Birth DATE,
  Driving_Lic_No VARCHAR2 (15),
  CONSTRAINT PK_Ind_Customer  PRIMARY KEY ( Customer_ID ),
constraints fk_Ind_Customer foreign key (Customer_ID) references Customer (Customer_ID));
```

--commands to create tables

```
CREATE TABLE Individual_Hire (
  Ind_Hire_ID VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    Commencing_DT Date,
    Finishing_DT Date,
    Duration_Days NUMBER (6,2),
    Customer_ID NUMBER (15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Location_ID NUMBER (5) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Vehicle_ID NUMBER (10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Accessory_hire_ID NUMBER (5) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
      constraints fk_Customer foreign key (Customer_id) references Customer (Customer_ID),
    constraints fk_location foreign key (location_id) references location (location_id),
    constraints fk_Vehicle foreign key (Vehicle_ID) references Vehicle (Vehicle_ID),
constraints fk_Accessory_hire foreign key (Accessory_hire_ID) references Accessory_hire (Accessory_hire_ID));
```

--commands to create tables

```
CREATE TABLE Corporate_Hire (
  Corp_Hire_ID NUMBER (10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
      Commencing_DT Date,
    Finishing_DT Date,
    Duration_Days NUMBER (6,2),
       Customer_ID NUMBER (15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Location_ID NUMBER (5) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Vehicle_ID NUMBER (10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Accessory_hire_ID NUMBER (5) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
      constraints fk_Customer foreign key (Customer_id) references Customer (Customer_ID),
    constraints fk_location foreign key (location_id) references location (location_id),
    constraints fk_Vehicle foreign key (Vehicle_ID) references Vehicle (Vehicle_ID),
constraints fk_Accessory_hire foreign key (Accessory_hire_ID) references Accessory_hire (Accessory_hire_ID));
```

--commands to create tables

```
CREATE TABLE Location (
Location_ID NUMBER (5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  Address_1 VARCHAR2 (20), 
  Address_2 VARCHAR2 (25),
  Postcode VARCHAR2 (15) NOT NULL,
  Town VARCHAR2 (15) NOT NULL,
  TelNo NUMBER (15),
  Email VARCHAR2 (35));
```

--commands to create tables

```
CREATE TABLE Vehicle_Class(
    Class_ID NUMBER (10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  Class_type VARCHAR2 (15) NOT NULL);
```

--commands to create tables

```
CREATE TABLE Vehicle (
  Vehicle_ID NUMBER (10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  Make VARCHAR2 (25),
  Reg_No VARCHAR2 (15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  Colour VARCHAR2 (15) NOT NULL,
    Model VARCHAR2 (15), 
  Mileage NUMBER (10,3),
  Daily_Charge NUMBER (7,3),  
    Class_ID NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
constraint fk_Vehicle_Class foreign key (Class_ID) references Vehicle_class (Class_ID));
```

--commands to create tables

```
CREATE TABLE Accessory (
  Accessory_ID NUMBER (10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  Accessory_type VARCHAR2 (30), 
  Price NUMBER (5,2));
```

--commands to create tables

```
CREATE TABLE Accessory_hire (
    Accessory_hire_ID NUMBER (5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Customer_ID NUMBER (15) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    Days_hired NUMBER (5) NOT NULL, 
 Accessory_ID NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,  
 CONSTRAINT FK_Customer foreign key (Customer_id) references Customer (Customer_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Accessory foreign key (Accessory_id) references Accessory (Accessory_id));
```

Comment: can you show error text?

Comment: Oracle or MySQL? Title says Oracle, tags say MySQL. Pick one and tag appropriately.

Comment: Edit your question, and add the **full error message** and also highlight the place in the code causing the error.

Comment: Move the FK definitions to ALTER TABLE statements after all of the tables have been created.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when creating `Individual_Hire`, you add constraints to tables which are created later, like `location` and `vehicle`.

It really should say so in the error text.

Comment: Oraclebegginer  , don;t know how to write a group by and having clause with more than three tables; below clause shows an error; any help?                                                                         
 SELECT Accessory_ID, Customer_ID, Accessory_Hire_ID, Accessory_Type
FROM Accessory, Accessory_Hire, Customer
Group by Accessory_type
WHERE Accessory_type.Customer_ID = Customer_ID.Accessory_hire
HAVING Accessory_ID count 101 and 103
ORDER BY Accessory_ID Desc;